# Getting DLL load failed while importing keras

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

pip install keras

import keras
gives the following error:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>       ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
>       Below is the traceback from this internal error.
>       ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
>       Below is the traceback from this internal error.
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
>           exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           import keras
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
>           from . import utils
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in 
>           from . import conv_utils
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
>           from .. import backend as K
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 1, in 
>           from .load_backend import epsilon
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in 
>           from .tensorflow_backend import *
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
>           import tensorflow as tf
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 101, in 
>           from tensorflow_core import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core__init__.py", line 40, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 50, in **getattr**
>           module = self._load()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 44, in _load
>           module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>           from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>           raise ImportError(msg)
>       ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>       Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>       for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>       above this error message when asking for help.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2033, in showtraceback
>           stb = value._render_traceback_()
>       AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1095, in get_records
>           return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
>           return f(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 347, in _fixed_getinnerframes
>           records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
>           frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
>           filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
>           if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '**loader**', None) is not None:
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
>           if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '**file**'):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 50, in **getattr**
>           module = self._load()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 44, in _load
>           module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>         File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>         File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>         File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>         File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>         File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>         File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>         File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>         File "", line 728, in exec_module
>         File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core__init__.py", line 42, in 
>           from . _api.v2 import audio
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core_api\v2\audio__init__.py", line 10, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in 
>           from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 50, in **getattr**
>           module = self._load()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 44, in _load
>           module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>           from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>           raise ImportError(msg)
>       ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
>           exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           import keras
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
>           from . import utils
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in 
>           from . import conv_utils
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
>           from .. import backend as K
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 1, in 
>           from .load_backend import epsilon
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in 
>           from .tensorflow_backend import *
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
>           import tensorflow as tf
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 101, in 
>           from tensorflow_core import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core__init__.py", line 40, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 50, in **getattr**
>           module = self._load()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 44, in _load
>           module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>           from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>           raise ImportError(msg)
>       ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>       above this error message when asking for help.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2033, in showtraceback
>           stb = value._render_traceback_()
>       AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>       Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>       See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>       for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>       above this error message when asking for help.
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
>           exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           import keras
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
>           from . import utils
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in 
>           from . import conv_utils
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
>           from .. import backend as K
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 1, in 
>           from .load_backend import epsilon
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in 
>           from .tensorflow_backend import *
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
>           import tensorflow as tf
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 101, in 
>           from tensorflow_core import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core__init__.py", line 40, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 50, in **getattr**
>           module = self._load()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 44, in _load
>           module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>           from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>           raise ImportError(msg)
>       ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>       Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>       See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>       for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>       above this error message when asking for help.
>       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>         File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>           return _load(spec)
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>       Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>       See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>       for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>       above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: How did you install keras?

Comment: @Kris pip install keras

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with Keras, it's your installation of Tensorflow that's not correct. Try to run `python -c 'import tensorflow'`. It should fail in your current situation.

If you're using Tensorflow-GPU, installation of required third party software can be tricky. You'll find instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

For Tensorflow-CPU, installation may sometimes fail if your processor does not support AVX instructions (At a certain point, Tensorflow started to use AVX during build, so if your processor does not support it, import will crash). In this case, you need to install an older version.

I'm not sure but I think Tensorflow 1.12 is the latest version before they started to enable AVX. Give it a try with:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.12
```